# Chat-bot for Facebook posts

Tags: facebook, chatbot, chatfuel

Is there any way to apply the chatbot for the Facebook posts. I'm using the Chatfuel for the messenger. It works when anyone starts a conversation on messenger.
But when I made a post by applying the **Send Message** button, the chatbot doesn't work on the posts.
I tried by giving the messenger link in the post. But it doesn't work.
Is there any way, when the user clicks on the Send Message button in the post. The chatbot opens in the messenger.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, Let me know you that you are wondering for solution in not a right direction.

Here is a guide to add Chat-bot on facebook post:
To add a Chat-bot for facebook posts you should look for facebook advertisements. you will get a feature of Add CTA button in the post that you have shared on facebook. For more information regarding this, I suggest you to login with facebook, create a post, go to adds section and there you will find that how can you boost or promote your post and can apply Chat-bot on a particular post. Thanks